Can't Increase Throughput for Standalone Instance
I have been working with Milvus v2.2.9 in standalone mode using Docker Compose, running without any CPU limits. My current setup involves creating an index with 1 million embeddings using the IVF_SQ8 indexing method. I've wrapped the Milvus search function (collection.search(...), _async=True) inside an asynchronous function.
When I send hundreds of asynchronous calls to this function, I observe that the CPU usage peaks at around 250%, accompanied by certain latency. Increasing the number of asynchronous calls doesn't enhance CPU usage, which remains at approximately 250%, but it does lead to increased latency. My machine is equipped with 16 virtual CPUs.
To address this, I attempted to adjust the maxReadConcurrentRatio to 100.0 in the milvus.yaml configuration file. Unfortunately, this change did not result in any improvement in CPU usage.
Is there a method to increase CPU utilization without negatively affecting latency? Am I overlooking any configuration options that could optimize performance?

The reason why no significant improvement in CPU usage is seen is because 1 million embeddings is actually considered a small dataset. If you were to increase the data to 10 million, you would be able to see an obvious increase in CPU usage.
Also, given that large data sets have more segments, it is more suitable to use parallel searching with several query nodes deployed, instead of searching one segment at a time with the one query node in standalone mode.
